# Checking XML values in a List

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I have a list of string containing number like below 
{"2","5","7"}

Also i have an xml like the below

```
<Product>
   <Record>
      <Categories>
        <SubCategories>  
           <References>2</References>
           <References>1</References>
           <References>10</References>
        </SubCategories>
      </Categories>
      <Categories>
        <SubCategories>  
           <References>154</References>
            <References>75</References>
           <References>0</References>
        </SubCategories>
      </Categories>
      <Categories>
        <SubCategories>  
           <References>7</References>
        </SubCategories>
      </Categories>          
   </Record>
</product>
```

I want to retrieve all the categories in a seperate xml file whose refernce value contain atleast one of the value present in the list mentioned above

I am stuck on how to proceed

```
xmldoc.load(filepath) (xmldoc is the xmldocument of the file)
Dim CategoriesList = xmldoc.descendants("Record")
for each item in CategoriesList 
   Dim SubCategoriesList = item.descendants("Subcategories")
Next
```

Please let me know on how to get check these values and get the required categories

Answer (score 0):

You can check that "Categories" elements has "References" with one of the values by using `Any` and `HashSet(Of String)`

```
Dim required = New String() {"1", "2", "3"}.ToHashSet()
Dim product = XDocument.Load("path-to-file")

Dim categories = product.Descendants("Categories").
    Where(Function(category) category.
        Descendants("References").
        Any(Function(r) required.Contains(r.Value))
    ).
    ToArray()
```

HashSet is to reduce amount of enumerations of values, `HashSet.Contains` check for value with only one operation O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but what does category refers to. Also the first line i get an error when i use ToHashSet. it seems it is not a member of String()

Comment: Import `System.Linq`?

Comment: category is `XElement`

Comment: Are you mixing vb.net with C# because I get red squiggles. Don't recognize => in vb.net.